# "Get" Child Variable from Parent Component

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I have LWC parent and child component. The parent component is a form that has a submit button. Upon submission, I want the parent component to access a specific variable in a specific child component.

Right now the only approaches that I am aware of for passing data are:

1. Events
2. Event Bubbling

Is there a way to "Get" a variable on-demand from the parent component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child can expose properties and methods to the parent via the @api decorator.

As a getter property:

```
export default class Child extends LightningElement {
  #displayState; // private variable
  @api get displayState() {
    return this.#displayState;
  }
}
```

Which the parent can then read:

```
const childDisplayState = this.template.querySelector('c-child').displayState;
```

You can also make this a public method:

```
export default class Child extends LightningElement {
  #displayState; // private variable
  @api getDisplayState() {
    return this.#displayState;
  }
}
```

Which you call as a method:

```
const childDisplayState = this.template.querySelector('c-child').getDisplayState();
```

Typically, it does make more sense for the child to keep the parent updated, but if you need this on-demand communication, either of these techniques can work.

Comment: Please change your name for sfdcgod

Comment: First snippet says getter but it is actually a method. Basically, both snippet 1 and 2 are same.

Comment: @javanoob a getter is a special type of function that looks like a property. So, while they are both function-like, you cannot call a getter like you would a function. That's why the terminology is written as it is.